# Excel: How can I find all the occurrences of the matching columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Consider I have the following table (unsorted):

| Name | ID | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 1 | 1234 |
| John Doe | 1 | 6524 |
| Jane Doe | 2 | 6346 |
| Jane Doe | 2 | 1241 |
| Jane Doe | 2 | 3634 |

And another one like this:

| Name | Account 1 | Account 2 | Account 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe |  |  |  |
| Jane Doe |  |  |  |

I need to find all the matching "accounts" for the second table from the first to end up like this:

| Name | Account 1 | Account 2 | Account 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 1234 | 6524 | n/a |
| Jane Doe | 6346 | 1241 | 3634 |

Account number order are not important (i.e. same order as in table 1 or sorted somehow). Is that possible without macros? I have no issues in finding first match with both VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH combination like this formula:

```
=INDEX($'Table 1'.A:C; MATCH(A5;$'Table 1'.A:A;0); 3; 1)
```

but totally clueless on how to get "next match".

Answer (score 0):

for now, some workaround, you can try to do two tables from table where you have ID, so create one table with ID=1 and second table with ID=2 and then do search vertically for each one, writes theoretically, it can be done more or less, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$A19,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1),COLUMN(A1))),"N/A")
```

Put that formula in cell B19 (The way I have it set up) and copy to any cells you may need.
Note: This will output any match, even if there are account doubles!

[image]

Take a look here for more info (on multiple results from INDEX/MATCH):
https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-columns

Comment: That didn't worked "out of box", but thanks for the link. I'll try to dig further a bit more.

Comment: When I say "copy to any cells you may need", i mean you need to copy it to the top-left-most cell of your result table, and copy that cell (either using the fill handle, or copying the cell itself - NOT the formula, rather the cell) to the other cells... If your data is structured the way it is in the photo, it should work.

Is your result table on a different page?